# Search large Json/csv fle and output results with a live search style

Tags: javascript, arrays

I guess i have a noob question here.
I have a huge Json file (30MB) that i would like to parse with a Jquery web app.

Now, the ideal would be to load it into local storage, regex what i want and show the results.
I would like it to start showing the results as soon as i type (google style) but it looks like every attempt i've made the app just hangs.
If i reduce the Json file to 1 MB then it works.

Does anybody know how to do that? maybe with an example that i can see?

thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to ask this question on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to **not** use this method for search. Because even if you will manage to make your search quicker it will take very long time to download 30MB file.

What you could do is convert your data from JSON to SQL and do search by sending AJAX calls to the server from your javascript code.

For further optimizations you can send AJAX calls only after search term's length exceeds certain number of characters probably 3.